# Async validation with Angular JS $parsers.push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular 1.5.8 and I would like to create a custom directive for email validation. 
I am using modelCtrl.$parsers.push to capture what the user is typing.

1. I test the text with an email regex, as long as the text is not a valid email, I programmatically set the model to 'invalid' in the directive.
2. When the text match the email regex I perform the async validation :

a. On success (which means in success callback) : I return the viewValue so the model should be equal to the viewValue

b. On fail (which means in fail callback) : I return the 'invalid' because I want the model to be set to 'invalid'.

The email validator async call is a fake on purpose, I want to be in the case 2.b. The problem here is that the case 2.b is not working, the model is set to empty instead of 'invalid', can you tell me why??

I have [plunkered](https://plnkr.co/edit/V4ufx5ETfbpHZdVjLU4t) the issue, and here is my custom directive

```
app.directive('validEmail', function($http) {

return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(checkForEmail);

    function checkForEmail(viewValue) {
      var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
      if (!emailRegex.test(viewValue)) {
        // Case 1.
        modelCtrl.$setValidity('validEmail', false);
        return 'invalid';
      } else {
        // Case 2. When the email match the regex we perform the async validation
        $http.get("http://verify-mail.org/index.php")
          .then(
            function success(response) {
              // Case 2.a
              modelCtrl.$setValidity('validEmail', true);
              return viewValue;
            },
            function fail(response) {
              // Case 2.b
              console.log('fail callBack')
              modelCtrl.$setValidity('validEmail', true);
              return 'invalid';
            });
      }
    }
  }
};});
```

Comment: I think angular's `ngModelController.$asyncValidators` would be best to use here

Comment: And in the `fail` callback you still set the validity to `true`: `modelCtrl.$setValidity('validEmail', true);`

Comment: @devqon: thanx for your answer, I had confilct with other directives when using ngModelController.$asyncValidators, isn't it possible to fix my issue without $asyncValidators?

Comment: I think it would be wiser to fix the problem with `$asyncValidators` than to monkey patch `$parsers` to do asynchronous validation.